# angular2 observable scan once then subscribe by many async

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to bind to shared observable two times in different moments. The second binding gets `null` when evaluated first time until next item appears.

here is component class:

```
export class App {
  subject = new BehaviorSubject(1);
  scan = this.subject.scan((current, change) => current + change, 0).share();
  other = this.scan.map(item => item);
}
```

and here is the template:

```
<div>
  <button (click)="clickedScan=true">show scan</button>
  <button (click)="clickedOther=true">show other</button>
  <button (click)="subject.next(1)">next</button>
  <div *ngIf="clickedOther">
    other | async: <b>{{ '' + (other | async) }}</b>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="clickedScan">
    scan | async: <b>{{ '' + (scan | async) }}</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4eSj4F4ENvZDLwEwcOBS?p=preview) (**update**: plunker updated to accepted answer)

`share()` is needed since otherwise `scan` method is being called repeatedly for each subscriber but then the next `async` binding done after some time has no access to last element. Without using `share()` all bindings work from the very beginning but then `scan` is called twice for each `subject.next()` call (on separate item instances in this plunker example). I would like to avoid this duplicated `scan` calls for many reasons - at least to not repeat exactly same job with same result for each subscriber.

I wonder what is the correct way to avoid multiple `share` (i.e. using some other `Observable` method) calls and still provide last element whenever new `async` will be bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, you need a hot observable so that you share a subsription rather than having separate subscriptions. You might be interested in this video by Andre: https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-demystifying-cold-and-hot-observables-in-rxjs. You might also be interested in Paul Taylor's talk from Reactive 2015: https://youtu.be/QhjALubBQPg?t=385

Basically, you can rewrite your code like so:

```
import {Subject, ReplaySubject} from "rxjs/Rx"; // only really need these two

/* your other code */

export class App {

  // plain old subject for clicks
  // i believe you can get an event stream somewhere?
  // sorry, i don't know angular2
  subject = new Subject();

  // replays the last event for observers on subscription
  main = new ReplaySubject(1);

  // you could apply transforms here if you want
  scan = this.main
  other = this.main

  constructor() {
    // take the events that come in
    this.subject

      // start our observable with an initial event
      .startWith(0)

      // when subject emits, this will run and update
      .scan((current, change) => current + change)

      // now we can subscribe our replay subject
      .subscribe(this.main);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is really good answer. I've updated plunker and also used in own more complex case - works as expected and it does play well with recent angular2 beta and RxJS 5 beta. Thank you!